# why does not the string appear in the word fille

Tags: python, tkinter, python-docx

My problem is that i run my code, then the tkinter window appears , and there I have a input function with the name "Exemplu1" , then I use the python-docx library and print the variable "Exemplu1" in the new word file. But the variable does not appear in the word file.

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path
import docx
doc = docx.Document()
root = Tk(className='ModifyTheFile - MDF')



save_path = r'C:\Users\Example\Desktop\TextForChangeThefile'
## Numele primei fise din folder
name_of_file = "Fisa 123"
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".docx")    


Exemplul1 = Entry(root)
Exemplul1.pack()


def myClick():
    doc.add_paragraph('Adresa lu Mister este ' + Exemplul1.get())


myButton = Button(root , text="Exemplu", command=myClick)
myButton.pack()

doc.add_paragraph('Adresa lu Mister este ' + Exemplul1.get())

doc.save(completeName)
root.geometry("1000x700")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You forgot to call `docx.save(completeName)` inside `myClick()`.

Comment: The `Exemplul1.get()` at the top level of your code is being executed about a millisecond after the Entry was created.  The user cannot possibly have typed in anything yet, in fact the Entry hasn't even appeared on the screen yet.